# Integrating Log-Normal PDF in sympy

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

Why won't SymPy integrate a standard Log-Normal PDF to 1?

I'm running the following code in Python 3.x and SymPy 1.0.1:

```
from sympy.stats import density, LogNormal
from sympy import Symbol, integrate, oo

mu, sigma = 0, 1
z = Symbol('z')
X = LogNormal('x', mu, sigma)
f = density(X)(z)

integrate(f, (z, 0, oo))
```

which should(?) return 1 but outputs:

```
sqrt(2)*Integral(exp(-log(z)**2/2)/z, (z, 0, oo))/(2*sqrt(pi))
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, Sympy fails to find the closed form solution of this integral.

You can, however, help Sympy perform the integration. One approach is to perform a transformation of the integration variable with the hope that it will result in a simpler integrand expression that Sympy can handle. Sympy offers a convenient [`transform()`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/integrals/integrals.html#sympy.integrals.Integral.transform) method for this purpose.

```
import sympy as sp
import sympy.stats

mu, sigma = 0, 1
z = sp.Symbol('z', nonnegative=True)
X = sympy.stats.LogNormal('x', mu, sigma)

f = sympy.stats.density(X)(z)
I = sp.Integral(f, (z, 0, sp.oo))
print(I)
```

[image]

This is the original integral form, which Sympy fails to evaluate. (Note the use of `sympy.Integral` which returns an unevaluated integral.) One (obvious?) transformation of the integration variable is `z -> exp(z)`, which results in a new integral as follows

```
I2 = I.transform(z,sp.exp(z))
print(I2)
```

[image]

Now, we may call the [`doit()`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/integrals/integrals.html#sympy.integrals.Integral.doit) method to evaluate the transformed integral:

```
I2.doit()
```

> `1`